# Custom Datagrid Event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, eventtrigger

I have 2 Extended Toolkit `Datagrids` in a window tied to 2 observable collections called Accounts and History. I would like to bind the cell edit ended event of the History `DataGrid` to a Command in my view model so that I can, among other things, update a value in the Accounts observable collection and have it reflected in the view.

To test that everything could work I used the below event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
       <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCmd}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This successfully triggered the command in the view model, made a static change in the observable collection and updated the view. So everything was good.

If I change the `EventName` to be `CellEditEnded` or so far every possible variation I can think of; nothing happens.

So, what event name should I use to capture the Cell Edit Ended event of the WPF Extended Toolkit `DataGrid`? Any help would be great, I have no idea where to go from here.

Edit:

I found [this post](http://xceed.com/CS/forums/post/33644.aspx) that suggested using a separate class to raise the `CellEditEnded` event. But I can't figure out how I am supposed to raise the custom event. Can any one explain how this should be used? Using the `CellEditEnded` event in EventTrigger as per the post still doesn't work.

```
public class MyDataGridControl : DataGridControl
{
    public MyDataGridControl()
    {
        this.AddHandler( Cell.EditEndedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler( MyDataGridControl.OnCellEditEnded ) );
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler CellEditEnded;

    private void RaiseCellEditEnded( RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        var handler = this.CellEditEnded;
        if( handler == null )
            return;

       handler.Invoke( this, e );
   }

   private static void OnCellEditEnded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
   {
       var dataGrid = ( MyDataGridControl )sender;
       Debug.Assert( dataGrid != null );

       dataGrid.RaiseCellEditEnded( e );
   }
}
```

Edit 2:

I have now discovered [this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mitchel.sellers/CustomEventsAndDelegatesOverview11202006094351AM/CustomEventsAndDelegatesOverview.aspx) which seemed promising. I adapted the code into the below and the class above does execute but the `CellEditEnded` event still doesn't fire.

```
private void HistoryDataGrid_EditEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGridControl mydatagridcontrol = new MyDataGridControl();
    mydatagridcontrol.CellEditEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(mydatagridcontrol_CellEditEnded);            
    mydatagridcontrol.RaiseEvent(e);
}
void mydatagridcontrol_CellEditEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I feel as though there should be something in the `void mydatagridcontrol_CellEditEnded` part but I don't know what I would put there.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks!